# Tab delimited txt file reading int value from string array

Tags: c#, int, arrays, textreader

I am using TextReader to read in each line of a tab delimited file.
For each line that it reads I split on the tabs and populate a string array.
I can then access specific positions in the string array to get the values.

This works great for strings like: userWorkload.SSN = arrColumns[0];
However, I get an error message at runtime when I try to convert one of the columns to an int: userWorkload.contactHours = Convert.ToInt32(arrColumns[9]);

Here is my code:

```
List<UserWorkload> userWorkloads = new List<UserWorkload>();
TextReader tr = File.OpenText("fall11-tab.txt");
string strLine = string.Empty;
string[] arrColumns = null;
while ((strLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     UserWorkload userWorkload = new UserWorkload();

     arrColumns = strLine.Split('\t');
     userWorkload.SSN = arrColumns[0];
     userWorkload.contactHours = Convert.ToInt32(arrColumns[9]);     

     userWorkloads.Add(userWorkload);
 }
```

and the UserWorkload class just contains simple getter / setters:

```
class UserWorkload 
{
     public string SSN { get; set; }
     public int contactHours { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my error:
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at Snyder5Creator.InputFileReader.buildRowList() in C:\Users\baxter.NET\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\User5Creator\User5Creator\InputFileReader.cs:line 31
   at Snyder5Creator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\baxter.NET\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\User5Creator\Snyder5Creator\Program.cs:line 24

Line 31 is: userWorkload.contactHours = Convert.ToInt32(arrColumns[9]);

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post that text file, too? Obviously it's blowing up at that element, but I'd need to see the element to be of more help. I'd probably use TryParse(), though, as a start.

Comment: You were right it ended up being bad data hidden in one of the rows.
Thanks for the TryParse() tip, everything working as expected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have invalid data in one or more of the records. If you're OK with ignoring these errors, you could use int.TryParse:

```
 int parsedNumber;
 userWorkload.contactHours = int.TryParse(arrColumns[9], out parsedNumber) ? parsedNumber : -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this in a try-catch, too.

```
List<UserWorkload> userWorkloads = new List<UserWorkload>();
TextReader tr = File.OpenText("fall11-tab.txt");
string strLine = string.Empty;
string[] arrColumns = null;
while ((strLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     UserWorkload userWorkload = new UserWorkload();

     arrColumns = strLine.Split('\t');
     userWorkload.SSN = arrColumns[0];
     if(!int.TryParse(arrColumns[9], out userWorkload.contactHours)
     {
        //Throw something like InvalidArgumentException here or set to a safe value (-1?)
     }     

     userWorkloads.Add(userWorkload);
 }
```